# how to get dataframe column index by cell value

Tags: python

i have a dataframe look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nslr2.png)

how can i get the column index base on the cell value exist `.xml` which is 4 in my dataframe ?

Here is my code:

```
df = fileserver
for index in df:
    df1 = df[index].str.contains(".xml")
    print(df1)
```

for the result `True`, i don't know how to find the index, please help and thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may track which column does indeed contain a pattern `.xml` using the following code. For the example below, the column of interest has index 2.

First, create a sample dataframe for your example.

```
import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,"3.xml"], [4,5,"6.xml"]])  
>>> df
   0  1      2
0  1  2  3.xml
1  4  5  6.xml
```

Now, check for your pattern among all cells of the dataframe.

```
>>> df_filtered = df.applymap(lambda cell: str(cell).endswith(".xml")) 
>>> df_filtered
       0      1     2
0  False  False  True
1  False  False  True
```

Finally, keep columns if at least one cell was found with the desired pattern.

```
>>> [column for column, count in df_filtered.sum().to_dict().items() 
     if count > 0]
[2]
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my life =)